# Create an image using vector and Raster layer QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to create a map with one vector layer (a state shapefile) and another vector layer/raster layer containing desired data in QGIS. When I load both the layers in QGIS, in order to obtain image I always save as JPEG (under Project -- save as image) and then edit it in paint tool of Windows by removing the unnecessary areas around the state image, by rubbing it with an eraser.

Is their a method by which this eraser practice can be skipped to save time?

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way of doing this. Firstly, what datasets do you have? And importantly, what is it that you are trying to achieve??

Comment: You could use the **Print Composer** which is specifically designed to create high-quality images :)